# Trigger to send a email when fields are updated

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, email-template, apex-email-service

I have one custom Object. I'm modifying and saving few records at a time.

[image]
When i click on Next button these three records are saving.

I need to send a email to all user under one profile whenever made change to fields of one or more than one records. The email should contain All fields data.

Ex: If there fields get modified, the all modified records data should be club
in one email and send to users as shown in below fig.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If those records are related somehow (if you can get the fields in a single record using relationships), you could set up a workflow rule to fire when certain fields are changed, and send the email to specific profiles.

If they are not, then you will have to use the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` class like in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82583/singleemailmessage-settargetobjectid-but-do-not-send-to-target), but you'll have to create your email body in the code (the HTML or plain text).

Comment: But How can i club all modified records in one email? like i show in above picture.

Comment: By either referencing relatioship fields (like Main__r.Object1__r.Field_A__c and Main__r.Object2__r.Field_A__c) or, if you are using code, querying them.